# FuelPHP oil refine migrate not working

Tags: php, ubuntu-10.04, fuelphp

I'm stuck at the beginning of a new site.
It's my first time, trying to use oil for generation / migration.

I successfully create a model using oil and now I want to migrate it, but

```
php oil refine migrate
```

gives me an error:

```
Error - invalid data source name in COREPATH/classes/database/pdo/connection.php on line 94
```

With a little bit of research I found out, that at least I'm not completely alone with this error, though none of the discussions I saw has been solved so far.

My db-configuration is all fine and regarding some hints I even overwrote php-cli's php.ini with the one, apache is using.

But no luck at all.

Anybody out there, who knows a solution? Any help appreciated!!!

EDIT:
I wanted to go on developing even without oil but now found that I can't even run migration from php. It's the same error message which doesn't help at all.
Please guys, anybody just has to know a solution...

Answer (score 1):

have you set the database conneection in the file: fuel/app/config/development/db.php? and is in the correct form:

```
return array(
    'default' => array(
        'connection' => array(
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fuel_intro',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
        ),
    ),
);
```

By the error it sounds like you may have the wrong sytax in your config.
I hope this is helpful, if not please post your db config file source.

Comment: I'm almost shure that I do have all config set correctly. I'm at work right now with no access to my code but I'm going to check my config. I'll let you know if it's correct... Thanks!